# Text to relocate upon maximizing window

Tags: css

Here is my problem folks, when I maximize the window, I would like the status, Due date, to be in a location which is with respect to the page, i.e in similar locations not at the same position. Upon maximizing, I want Status, Due Data, and To to always move towards the right when maximized, or when the page is expanded. I'm new to CSS. Thank you for you time, I look forward to your assistance.

NOT MAXIMIZED
[image: BEFORE]
MAXIMIZED
[image: AFTER]
Above are the screen shots,

Here is my CSS attempt:

```
#center-header-status
{
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14;
    padding:25px;
    float:left;
    color:#5E5E5E;
    bottom:7px;
    text-align:justify;

}

#center-header-duedate
{
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14;
    padding:25px;
    float:left;
    color:#5E5E5E;
    bottom:7px;

}

#center-header-to
{
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14;
    padding:25px;
    float:left;
    color:#5E5E5E;
    margin-left:5px;
    bottom:7px;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Try working through it yourself and when you get hung up, please ask a specific question. As it sits, you have said what you want it to do, but don't have a question. Are you planning on us doing it for you?

Comment: No Jason, my question is why is it moving, and if someone can put me on the right direction. I provided my code, for my attempt. As of now, I've tried Justification, getting rid of the padding, using % instead of actual values, and no success yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this would be to use css3 media queries, check out
http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/